# How to call the Kinect Sensor Index when multiple kinect are used?

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

As in Initialize Kinect process, we normally see this:

```
hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &m_pNuiSensor);
```

which in my understanding is to create an instance of the Kinect sensor with a specified index. So assume I am having two kinect cameras, one should be with index 0 and another with index 1.

My question is,
how should I call this two instances respectively?

(I want to work on two kinect cameras simultaneously in NUI. So it might be needed to call Kinect0 and Kinect1 respectively to process their respective skeletal result using condition.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd want two `INuiSensor *` :

```
std::array<INuiSensor*, 2> m_pNuiSensors;
```

and create both of them with

```
hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &m_pNuiSensors[0]);
// Handle any error
hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(1, &m_pNuiSensors[1]);
// Handle any error
```

Comment: Can this two sensor work simultaneously at the same time if I define this way? or still the first initialized sensor will do the skeletal tracking only?